# mapping a distribution to it's parameter domain

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

The K-distribution is a special case of the variance gamma distribution, which in turn is a special case of the generalised hyperbolic distribution. The generalised hyperbolic distribution is a superclass containing the student T's distribution, Laplace distribution, hyperbolic distribution, normal inverse gaussian distribution among others.

> How do we recover a simplified form of the [K-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-distribution) from an integrating an unknown $1$-parameter distribution $\varphi(s;x)$ over it's support? Does this suggest $\varphi(s,x)$ is a special case of the generalised hyperbolic distribution as well?

Let's write down the $K$ distribution and set this equal to the integral of the unknown distribution:

$$ 2\sqrt{s}K_1(2\sqrt{s})=\int_a^b \varphi(s;x)~dx $$

The LHS is just $f_S(s,1,2)$ see the link above. Also $\varphi(s,x)$ is not normalised.

The integral reminds me of something called an integral transform. I suspect what's happening is that the distribution is being mapped from it's original domain to it's parameter domain, where we obtain a new distribution, in this case the simplified version of the K-distribution.

And now the parameter for the original distribution is the variable for the K-distribution. Does that make sense, and is this useful in any way to have this connection between distributions?